# why can't I see the frame number in beamer after my Mac update?

Tags: beamer

I have made a presentation with beamer and could see the frame number but i updated my MacBook to Mohave last week and I can't see the frame number after that? what should I do?I didn't change anything.

```
\documentclass[8pt,mathserif]{beamer}
\mode<beamer>
\mode<presentation>
%---------------------------------
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
%-------------------------------------------
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\newcommand{\comments}[1]{} 
\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{logo1}}
\usetheme{Luebeck}

\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structuresmallcapsserif}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\graphicspath{{./res/}}
\usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont{title}{shape=\itshape,family=\rmfamily}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red!80!black,bg=red!20!white}
\title{\bf{ Effective dynamics}}
\author[SS]{ \textcolor{blue}{SS}}
 \institute[ BB]{
  Supervisor:\\ Dr. F}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\small}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<handout:0>
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[pausesections]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get black frame numbers with your MWE. Can you share your .log file?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to share that. its too long to be added in a comment

Comment: try pastebin.com

Comment: unrelated to your problem: the `mathserif` option is deprecated, use `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` instead. Instead of `\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}` use the beamer documentclass option `xcolor={table}`. Don't load the same packages multiple times.  You don't need `\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}`, beamer loads them for you. `\usepackage{float}` does not make sense in a documentclass without floats and `\usepackage{times}` is deprecated.

Comment: Instead of messing with the arguments of macros like `\title` etc. adjust the respective templates, e.g. `\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}` and `\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=blue}`

Comment: This is the .log file of my entire presentation file. https://pastebin.com/wB9XheCt

Comment: This had been a bug in an old beamer version. Update your tex distribution. Current version of beamer is 3.55